# How to fetch IPFS data on Polygon Smart contract?

Tags: oracles, chainlink, polygon, ipfs, provable

On a project in solidity, on Polygon/Matic, I need to fetch data from IPFS.
So, an Oracle is mandatory, and I found 2 possible oracles:

**Provable (old Oraclize)** seems do not accept 2nd layer Polygon.
=> In this case, is there a solution to use Provable anyway, using for example a bridge Eth-Polygon?

**ChainLink** seems the good approach (Make a GET Request)
but I cannot find out *Oracle address* and *JobID* on [Chain.link](https://market.link/)
=> On the new Chain.link, How to find an Oracle address and JobID?
I tried to get information on [docs.chain.link](https://docs.chain.link/) and on [Linkpool](https://docs.linkpool.io/docs/overview). Also, chainlink Market seems to have been updated, compared to the information found on the [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ay4rXZhAefs&t=1s&ab_channel=Chainlink).

Are there other oracles able to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Since, it s not an obvious answer.

**Provable** support Polygon.
You can find on [provable](https://provable.xyz/index.html) an information proving, it s working on Polygon.
The green dot (status) brings to the operational systems where polygon is mentioned.
Also, a look on provableAPI.sol, show information about Polygon.
Rem: no testnet faucet available.*

Unfortunately, the number of transaction made on provable seems very low when I check their Nodes contracts.

**Chainlink**
It exists a website to search for nodes provider: https://www.chainlinkecosystem.com
And then, the good practice is to look on the node website to find information for adress and jobid

Answer (score 0):

UI of [Chain.link](https://chain.link/) was updated recently, and you can find a list of oracle addresses [here](https://docs.chain.link/docs/any-api/testnet-oracles/#operator-contracts) and Job IDs for multiple tasks [here](https://docs.chain.link/docs/any-api/testnet-oracles/#job-ids) for different test nets.

If you want to use Chainlink Any API in main net, 2 options:

1. You can find node operators in the official discord and ask them to provide a job id and operator contract address to you.
2. Set up your own Chainlink node. To set up a Chainlink node, you can [build from source code](https://github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink#install), [run it in a docker](https://docs.chain.link/docs/running-a-chainlink-node/#using-docker), or directly use the service on [naas.link](https://naas.link/) which is also managed by link.pool.

Find more details [here](https://docs.chain.link/docs/any-api/find-oracle/#find-a-job).

Comment: Thank you Frank for your answer.
My target, before to select Oracles solution, is to ensure that an Oracle is fitting my needs in term of: cost, complexity, security... So my expectation is to find a turnkey solution on Main net. 

1. Chainlink's Discord seems have been updated too: no solution to request JobId or operators
2. Set up your own Chainlink node: I prefer to avoid this solution (and focus on Turkey solutions).

Comment: yw Aurel. Your choice. Just mention that channel "node" in Chainlink discord is where you can find node operators.

Comment: We start to be far from the Software side, but it s necessary to understand the chainlink services. 
Btw, I dont find any open channel for question, neither a "Node" channel.

Comment: @Aurel maybe ask MOD to grant you the access to "Node" channel. Try the oracle address here https://docs.chain.link/docs/any-api/testnet-oracles/#operator-contracts.